# Read specific data from multiple text files in one directory in SAS

Tags: import, macros, sas

*** Resolved. The answer will be attached in the end. Thank you all for your help!

Thanks for reading this. I am working on a piece of code that was left by my former colleague, and trying to make some sense out of it.

The purpose is to read specific data (ex: value from row 1 & column 17, and row 12 & column 33) from multiple text files in one directory and put the data in a SAS table.

```
%macro cycle_through_server_records;

%local i next_file;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&SERVER_FILE)) ;
%let next_file = %scan(&SERVER_FILE, &i);
%let Ext =.TXT ;

DATA TEST.LIC_SERVER;
INFILE 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\TEST\&next_file&..TXT'   FIRSTOBS=1 OBS=12 
MISSOVER;
INPUT
@17 DATA_FILE $11.///////////
@33 SERVER_RECORDS_COUNTS $9. ;
RUN;

PROC APPEND BASE=TEST.SERVER_FILE DATA=TEST.LIC_SERVER FORCE;
RUN;

%END;
%MEND cycle_through_server_records;

%cycle_through_server_records;
```

The macro variable is set from metadata file via SQL query.

```
proc sql noprint;
select State 
     , compare_Date
     , Data_Source
     , Source_Date
     , file_name
     , Source_file_date
  into :total_state separated by ' ' 
     , :compare_date separated by ' '
     , :Data_Src separated by ' ' 
     , :Source_Cd_Date separated by ' '
     , :Server_file separated by ' '
     , :Src_file_dt separated by ' ' 
  from AUTO_SDS.config 
; 
quit;
```

Every time I ran it in SAS, I receive this error message "ERROR: Physical file does not exist, C:\Users\Name\Desktop\TEST\&next_file&..TXT". I am not sure what's wrong with the file path?

Also, with the error message, the code was still able to ran. But returned 9 repeated rows from only one text file (there are multiple text files in the directory). I am stuck. Can someone please help me with resolving the issue?

Thank you for your time and help in advance!

As suggested, I am posting the code I ran and the log file here. Thank you!

```
%LET Path_files = C:\Users\name\Desktop\TEST;

%macro cycle_through_server_records;
%local i next_file;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&SERVER_FILE)) ;
%let next_file = %scan(&SERVER_FILE, &i);

DATA TEST.LIC_SERVER;
INFILE "&Path_files\&next_file&..TXT"   FIRSTOBS=1 OBS=12 MISSOVER;
INPUT
@17 DATA_FILE $11.///////////
@33 SERVER_RECORDS_COUNTS $9. ;
RUN;

PROC APPEND BASE=TEST.SERVER_FILE DATA=TEST.LIC_SERVER FORCE;
RUN;

%END;
%MEND cycle_through_server_records;

%cycle_through_server_records;

PROC SORT DATA=TEST.SERVER_FILE NODUP;
BY DATA_FILE;
RUN;
```

There are 22 files in the directory, and their name are all in the following format "State_201708" and they are Text Document (.txt).

The output data set TEST.SERVER_FILE only has one file's data.

SAS log:

There are 8 error messages for 8 files in the directory (I am not sure why it's 8, instead of 21. Since only one file's data got captured successfully). The error message looks like the following:

ERROR: Physical file does not exist, C:\Users\name\Desktop\TEST\State_201708.TXT.

Thanks for your help!

*** Solution
With all your comments and a colleague's help, we found the cause of why it only worked for some files in the directory but not all. As Tom pointed out below, it was retrieving information from variable SERVER_FILE (from CONFIG table which is not used here).

What we did to make it work: we added an extra step before the macro to read all the file names from the directory and put them in a SAS table. And then turned that column into a variable. Replace SERVER_FILE with the new variable name. Now it worked!

Comment: Where are you setting the macro variable SERVER_FILE?

Comment: That's a very good question! I was searching the macro variable SERVER_FILE in my colleague's code. It only showed once in a different section of code. I will attach that part of the code below. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize if the format is a mass. I am not sure how to input code in comment section. The code shows that the SERVER_FILE variable is set from the AUTO_SDS.config table, which is not needed in the purpose of what I am trying to do. Code:     proc sql noprint;
select State ,compare_Date, Data_Source, Source_Date, file_name, Source_file_date
into :total_state separated by ' ' , :compare_date separated by ' ', :Data_Src separated by ' ' , :Source_Cd_Date separated by ' ', :Server_file separated by ' ', :Src_file_dt separated by ' '
from AUTO_SDS.config ;
quit;

Comment: I posted the code from your comment into the question.

Comment: Are you sure that the file it is complaining about exists on the machine where SAS is running? Are you sure that the userid that is running the SAS code has permission to read the files? Are you using a Unix file system where the case of letters in the filename make a difference?

Comment: Yes, the file that SAS complains about exists. Yes, I have permission to read as they are in a folder of my C drive. No, the files are simple text files. Their name are like "NY_201708", "DC_201708", and etc. The part I don't understand is some of the files can be read and some of them cannot. And I couldn't tell the differences between those files would cause this. They are in the same format but just for different state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the list of filename in a dataset you can use that to read the files.

```
data test.server_file;
  set auto_sds.config;
  length fname $256 ;
  fname = cats("&path_files\",file_name,".txt");
  if fileexist(fname) then do;
    infile in filevar=fname n=12 truncover ;
    input #1 @17 data_file $11. #12 @33 server_records_counts $9. ;
  end;
  else put 'ERROR: File not found ' fname= $quote.;
run;
```

Or if you want every file then you don't even need to start with a dataset.

```
%LET Path_files = C:\Users\name\Desktop\TEST;
data test.server_file;
  length fname filename $256 ;
  infile "&path_files\*" filename=fname eov=eov truncover ;
  input @;
  filename = fname ;
  if _n_=1 or eov then do;
    input @17 data_file $11. 
      /////////// @33 server_records_counts $9. 
    ;
    output;
  end;
  eov=0;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I guess that's the part where I am confused, is that I don't know why do we need the AUTO_SDS.CONFIG file? It's not needed for gathering the data from the text files into SAS. Is there a way I can skip the part of using AUTO_SDS.CONFIG?

Comment: Huh? Isn't AUTO_SDS.CONFIG the source for the list of the text files that you want to read?

Comment: I don't think so. I am sorry for the confusion. All the source files that I am trying to read are in the C:\Users\name\Desktop\TEST folder. AUTO_SDS.CONFIG was one of the table it used in my colleague's original code, but it was not related to what I am trying to do here. All I am trying to do is reading all the files from a folder in my C drive into SAS, and get specific data (DATA_FILE and SERVER_RECORDS_COUNTS) from each of the files and put in a SAS table.

Comment: So where do you get the list of files? Do you want all files in the folder? Only files whose names follow a pattern?  Are you sure all of the files have at least 12 lines?

Comment: I want the whole list of files in that directory. Every single file.

Answer (score 1):

You have single quotes around your file path.  Macro variables only resolve inside double quotes.  Try changing:

```
'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\TEST\&next_file&..TXT'
```

to

```
"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\TEST\&next_file..TXT"
```

I removed the extra ampersand, which would have resolved to nothing anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I tried with what you suggested, and it worked fine for some of the files in the directory, but not the others. For instance, there are 10 files in the directory, 7 of them succeed and 3 of them were not shown up in the TEST.SERVER_FILE.

Comment: Can you post your log?  There is not enough information to help right now..  Would need to know the value of the `SERVER_FILE` macro variable, and the names of the files in your directory.

Comment: I still got the same error message for some of the files, and it shows the path as "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\TEST\filename.TXT." in the error message. There is an extra . after the file name. Would that be where the issue come from? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added the full code I ran and the error message from the log in the post.